# Bubble sort em C inconsistente

Tags: c, classificação

Estou tentando criar a estrutura básica para um programa que utiliza o Bubble Sort. Porém, ao testar sua estrutura básica, vejo que o vetor final não está sendo retornado corretamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAMANHO 5

int main() {

    int vetor[TAMANHO-1],n1,n2,ctr,ctrInt;

    for(ctr=0;ctr<TAMANHO;ctr++) scanf("%d",&vetor[ctr]);

    for(ctr=0;ctr<TAMANHO;ctr++){
        for(ctrInt=0;ctrInt<TAMANHO-ctr-1;ctrInt++){
        n1=vetor[ctrInt];
        n2=vetor[ctrInt+1];
            if(n1>n2){
                vetor[ctrInt]=n2;
                vetor[ctrInt+1]=n1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(ctr=0;ctr<TAMANHO;ctr++) printf("%d",vetor[ctr]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E a troca dos valores também não está certa. Para trocar dois valores voce precisa de uma variavel temporaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int vetor[TAMANHO],n1,n2,ctr,ctrInt;
```

Você deve colocar na declaração do array o número de elementos que você quer e não o indice do ultimo elemento, ou seja, para ter um array com `TAMANHO` elementos você deve declarar `int vetor[TAMANHO]`.

Comment: Mas neste caso, eu não teria TAMANHO+1 termos, uma vez que os vetores começam com o termo número 0?

Comment: @Nucleus os valores continuanm indo de 0 a **TAMANHO - 1**, mas na declaração do array é esperado o número de elementos, não o indice do maior elemento, você pode ler mais [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/). Desculpa pela documentação em Inglês.

Comment: Não confunda o tamanho do array com a variação do índice utilizado para acessar um determinada posição do array. Por ex. int x[3]; define uma array de 3 posições e cada elemento utilizará um índice entre 0 e 2: x[0], x[1] e x[2].